# Illutrator save for web created dull images

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design

Hej!

This has never been a problem before and I have tried to look for an answer all over the web with no success.

I have created lots of illustrations (vectors) in illustrator before which I have used to create content for the web. Usually I save the images by choosing the option "Save for Web", which usually gives the images another glow (if I save them normally, they get this dull look)

I've done this many times before, but now all of the sudden, the pictures doesn't change from dull to this glowy look!???

Can anybody please help, I've been trying to solve this problem for so long now :(

Comment: Actually your settings should be such taht while editing you have teh same as what you see on web. So who knows how you had misconfigured illustrator before.

Comment: @Maria pictures of the effect and your export settings might help us help you

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options on the right side of the 'save for web' page. You could toy with these and look to see if the preview becomes more vivid with certain selections...

For example: If it's been accidentally set to 'gif' there's a chance that this'll limit the amount of colours, it'll render your image in a different shade.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dull colours in web images, such as in JPEGs or PNGs, are sometimes caused by not having the "Convert to sRGB" option selected when exporting. sRGB is the standard colour profile used for web images.

In the save for Web dialog, ensure this option is checked.

[image]